# React Native, let me know how to retrieve data in array from A class to B class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I am new to React Native. 
Sorry for asking simple question. 
So basically, the data from A class is retrieved into B class.

here is my code.

Class A.

```
export default class A extends Component {
render() {

var SampleNameArray = [ "Pankaj", "Rita", "Mohan", "Amit", "Babulal", "Sakshi" ];

 return (
   <Text>SampleNameArray[1]</Text>
);
}
}
```

Class B.

```
export default class B extends Component {

render(){
  return(   <Text>{ ???? How to retrieve SampleNameArray  }</Text> )}
```

Comment: u want `SampleNameArray ` or class containing it?

Comment: SampleNameArray's value :)

Comment: Is Class A a parent or child of Class B or are they not related at all?

Comment: They are not related :)

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779200/passing-props-to-screens-in-react-native and do tell me if you need any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you want to use `SampleNameArray` only then you don't need a class.

A simple named/default `export` will work.

In A :

```
export const SampleNameArray  =  [ "Pankaj", "Rita", "Mohan", "Amit", "Babulal", "Sakshi" ];
```

In B :

```
import {SampleNameArray} from 'path-to-A';
  // use `SampleNameArray`
```

In other word, you can make `A` as a service .

Comment: can I also do class containing?? if so, how can I do ??

Comment: u can.Simply create class and export an object  of class and then . use it to get your array.

Comment: well, if you do not mind, can you also update it as an answer.. sorry about this..