# Passing Props to Screens in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have started to learn React Native and as always begin by creating reusable components. I learnt how you can pass and access props while creating custom components.

I want to create a base screen in React Native, which has common properties and all screens in my app can set, like a title for example.

Below I'm creating a new Screen for the home page of my app

```
class APCComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() { //dummy function, will always get overridden in the child
        return (
            <View />
        );
    }
}

export default class Home extends APCComponent {
    //I somehow want to pass a string to the parent APCComponent
    //and want APCComponent use it to set the Header of the navigation

    constructor() {
        super({ title: 'Home' });
    }

    //Right now the following works, but in case I use a different type of Navigation,
    //I'll have to change all components. By just setting a string, I'm allowing my base
    //component to display the header
    static navigationOptions = { title: "Home" }; //from react-navigtion's StackNavigator

    render() {
        return <Button title="Sample Button" />;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: use react-native-router-flux for navigation. https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux, if you want i can show you demo with  reusable component.  and trust me in long term you will be using router-flux..

Comment: Thanks @SagarChavada, I have just started and react-native-router-flux looks interesting. I want to keep things generic and configurable for future changes. I have changed the code in my question. If you can please help me pass and set the header, that will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BaseComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (){
      <Header title={this.props.title} />
    }
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (){
      <BaseComponent title='this is your home screen' />
    }
  }
}
```

where `Header` component is also a separate reusable component.

you need to pass props(in our case 'title') from the upper level component to base level components like the above example.

Comment: Please see my question. Have changed my code in the question. I want to create a base component that handles header and any other common properties.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `HomeScreen`, props should be able to passed to `BaseComponent` through

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
...
```

does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm able to pass props from my HomeScreen to the BaseComponent. Now how do I set the StackNavigator's navigationOptions in BaseComponent? Adding the following line in Base's constructor did not work - 

navigationOptions = { title: props.title };